# CountIf does not work as expected when used multiple times in a function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Hello I am trying to run the following code to count the number of times something appears in a sheet.

```
Sub test()
  ' passes in what sheet (Sheet1) to search and which row (5) to write the results
  dummy = CountExample("Sheet1", 5)
End Sub

Function CountExample(Sheet As String, RowPopulate As Integer)
  Sheets(Sheet).Select ' Selects the appropriate sheet to search through
  Dim tmp As Integer

  ' Search for find1
  tmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells, "find1")
  Sheets("Recording Sheet").Select
  Range("C" & RowPopulate).Value = tmp ' Update and write the value in C5
  tmp = 0  'this does not seem to do anything


  ' something wrong with this one find2 should have 39 matches not 15
  ' Search for find2
  tmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells, "find2")
  Sheets("Recording Sheet").Select
  Range("E" & RowPopulate).Value = tmp ' Update and write the value in E5


End Function
```

When I just run the code to just search for find2 (after removing the code for searching for find1) I get 39 matches which is correct but if I run the code as above I get 15 matches for find2.

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: Your worksheet scope is not correct.

Comment: Thank you, I just figured it out by adding Sheet.Select before the second search

Comment: Please don't "select" things, and then use "Cells". This is a recipe for not knowing what is being searched...

Comment: Try it without relying on `Select`. I will give you an answer below.

Comment: @DavidZemens - I was about to do the same thing but will leave it up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of your worksheet/range objects is not correct. A common mistake, and one reason to avoid relying on constructs like `Select` and `Activate` methods, unless otherwise explicitly stated, a range object always refers to the `ActiveSheet`.

Try this instead (edited per Garys suggestion to use a subroutine instead of a function):

```
Sub test()
  ' passes in what sheet (Sheet1) to search and which row (5) to write the results
  CountExample "Sheet1", 5
End Sub


Sub CountExample(Sheet As String, RowPopulate As Integer)
   ' Selects the appropriate sheet to search through
  Dim tmp As Integer
  Dim ws as Worksheet
  Dim wsRecord as Worksheet

  Set ws = Worksheets(Sheet)
  Set wsRecord = Worksheets("Recording Sheet")

      ' Search for find1
      tmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Cells, "find1")
      wsRecord.Range("C" & RowPopulate).Value = tmp ' Update and write the value in C5
      tmp = 0  'this does not seem to do anything


      ' something wrong with this one find2 should have 39 matches not 15
      ' Search for find2
      tmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Cells, "find2")
      wsRecord.Range("E" & RowPopulate).Value = tmp ' Update and write the value in E5


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but now it seems to perform all the searches in the active sheet which is the 'Recording Sheet' It's almost as if With Sheets (Sheet) has no effect. A minor syntax fix, you forgot to put keyword 'Call' when calling the Sub

Comment: hmmm I think it should have worked are you sure you qualified the `Cells` with the leading period, like `.Cells`?  In any case, I made a more explicit revision which I think should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a Sub rather than a Function since you want to change a set of cells rather than return a single value

Comment: +1 while a VBA function can do this, it's probably not advisable. Best practice would be to use a subroutine to manipulate the worksheet object instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Sheets("Recording Sheet").Select` to switch to "Recording Sheet", but you are not switching back to `Sheet`.  So the second `CountIf` is occurring on "Recording Sheet".